# How does xrange() work inside of a while loop?

Tags: python

this is sort of a follow up question to a question I had [yesterday](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15778/how-can-i-make-this-code-better#comment16852528_12519166). Im a newbie to python and currently teaching myself using LPTHW by Zed Shaw. The code below is broken and i could use some help fixing it, im trying to make a random number generator for use with RPGs.

```
from random import randint
name = raw_input('\n Hello there. Please Type in your name > ')

print """
Hello {} & welcome to the Random Number Generator by Ray Weiss.
""".format(name)

upper = int(raw_input('Enter the type of dice you want to roll > '))

n = int(raw_input("How many D{} you'd like to roll? ".format(upper)))

for _ in xrange(n):
    print randint(1, upper)

prompt = """
Would you like to roll another D{}? Type 'yes', 'no', or 'quit'
""".format(upper)

answer = raw_input(prompt)

while answer == "yes":
    for _ in xrange(n):
            print randint(1, upper)
            prompt = """
            Would you like to roll another D{}? Type 'yes', 'no', or 'quit'
            """.format(upper)
            answer = raw_input(prompt)

if answer == "no":
    upper = int(raw_input('Enter the type of dice you want to roll > '))
    n = int(raw_input("How many D{} you'd like to roll? ".format(upper)))
    for _ in xrange(n):
        print randint(1, upper)
        prompt = """
        Would you like to roll another D{}? Type 'yes', 'no', or 'quit'
        """.format(upper)
        answer = raw_input(prompt)

if answer == "quit":
    print """
    Thank you {} for using the D{} RNG by Ray Weiss! Goodbye!
    """.format(name, upper)
```

Ideally what i want to happen is that it asks me first how many sided die i want and how many dice i want to roll. after that, i want it to ask me if i want to roll that same die and amount again, if i say yes, then it does it. if i say no, i want it to go back and ask me what sided die and how many die i want to roll again.

Edit: I think this code is a little better but its still not working

```
from random import randint

def roll(sides, num_of_dices):
    return [randint(1, sides) for i in range(num_of_dices)]

prompt = "> "

# Main Program

num_of_dices = input(prompt)
sides = input(prompt)


while True:
  results = roll(sides, num_of_dices)
  print results

  s = input(prompt)
  if s == 'quit':
      break
```

Comment: Hi! I'm glad you liked Lev Levitsky's answer and I realize you come from Stack Overflow, but unfortunately this question is off-topic on Code Review. The [faq](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq) explains it nicely, but basically non-working code should go to Stack Overflow, and working code you want to improve should come here. I'm going to flag this question, hoping that a nice moderator will be able to move it to SO. Have a nice day!

Comment: Agh this is the second question Ive done thats been in the wrong section, my apologies! I should have read the FAQ closer. Thanks Cygal!

Comment: I don't understand what you intend this to do. Also, I can't see a `while` loop!

Comment: Ok, you know that you need a while loop. Where is your attempt at using one?

Comment: Whoops I copied the wrong save, lemme fix that.

Comment: what python version you are using? 2.7 or 3? It really matters in this case!!

Comment: can you put this question little "short".. its really hard to read all. just write the piece where you are facing the trouble..

Comment: Im using 2.7 ill get rid of the first bit of code and just display the broken code. The original code will still be at my earlier question link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your program is going to be like this:

```
def roll(sides, num_of_dices):
    # returns some list

# main program

sides = input(...)
num_of_dices = input(...)

while True:
  results = roll(sides, num_of_dices)
  print results

  s = input(...)
  if s == 'quit':
      break
```

First try to implement and test `roll` separately and when it's ready, integrate it with the main program.

As to the implementation or `roll`, rolling N dices is the same as rolling one dice N times. In python, to perform an action N times and collect results, you use a list comprehension:

```
results = [action for i in range(N)]
```

so, your action is to roll one `sides`-sided dice and we need to repeat that `num_of_dices` times. Putting it all together,

```
def roll(sides, num_of_dices):
    return [roll_one_dice(sides) for i in range(num_of_dices)]
```

Comment: This rules! Thanks! but will this just give me the totals of the die rolls, or the results of each one? I would try to get it to work myself but that question is screwing with my head in terms of returning a list.

Comment: @lerugray: this will print the results of a single roll and then ask the user if he wants to continue. What I meant by "return a list" is that when you've got 5 6-sided dices, the result is going to be something like `[1, 2, 1, 6, 3]` - one number per dice.

Comment: I guess im just having some trouble figuring out how to implement roll, i assume ill have to use xrange() but im not really sure how to implement it in a function. Was I on the right track indenting things twice for the for _ in xrange(n) part in my original code?

Comment: @lerugray: I added some explanations to the post.

Comment: Still having some issues, I edited my question to show what i have now, but its still not working. It will let me ask for sides and number of dice, but after that it only lets me input one number, where as i would like it to ask me if i want to roll the same about of side/die again or if i want to set a new one.

Comment: @lerugray: sorry to say that, but I don't think I'll be able to assist you further. We're glad to answer specific technical questions here, but we don't provide online tutoring or step-by-step guidance. This is what books and tutorial sites are for. I hope you understand this and good luck with learning python.

Comment: Fair enough! More for me to learn! Thanks for all of your help so far, i really appreciate it!